# How to remove right border

Tags: html, css, border

Do you guys have any idea how to remove the right border on my drop down menu? I tried putting *right-border: none*, *right-border: hidden*, and *right-border: 0px* but nothing!

***HTML :***

```
<section class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> illustrations </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> portraits </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> environments </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> life drawings </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"> STORE </a>
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"> society6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"> redbubble </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> CONTACT </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

***CSS :***

```css
.menu {
height:29px;
width:100%;
/*background:orange;*/
}

.menu ul {
width:auto;
list-style-type:none;
font-family:"calibri", "arial";
}

.menu ul li {
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:left;
width:auto;
border-right: 2px solid purple;
margin-left:10px;
line-height:12px;
}

.menu ul li a {
display:block;
padding:3px;
color:#854288;
text-decoration:none; 
font-size:20px;
font-weight:strong;
padding-right:25px;

}

.menu ul li a:hover, .active {
color:#788d35
}

.menu ul li ul {
display:none;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:23px;
float:left;
padding-left:20px;
text-align:left;
margin-left: -30px;

}

.menu ul li ul li {
position:relative;
min-width:135px;
max-width:1350px;
width:100%;
}

.menu ul li ul li a {
padding: 3px;
margin-left: 1px;
border-right: hidden; /* <---- DOES NOT WORK */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes `border` from the main menu (after the last item **About**) :

```css
.menu ul li:last-child{ border:none; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4D5b8/)

If you also want to remove `border` from the nested `li`s, you should add `border:none` to `.menu ul li ul li` :

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4D5b8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   #right_border_less{

            border:solid;
            border-right:none;
        }
```

Comment: You should expand your answer to explain how and why this solves the OP's problem.  Answers are more useful when they include some context, instead of just code.